# How to add elements to a Boost.Tuple

Tags: c++, boost

Maybe this is a simple question, but I can't figure it out how can I add elements to a tuple. What I want is to iterate a vector and add every element into a tuple:

```
for(it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it)
{
   tuple.addElement(*it);
}
```

I dont see any specific method to add elements.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Isn't the length of a tuple fixed?

Comment: That is what i was wondering....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't "add elements" to a tuple. A tuple is not a container.

Sounds like perhaps you're looking for a `std::vector`, or perhaps [some other container](http://adrinael.net/containerchoice).

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use a tuple in my project, but now I know that the vector or other container is my only way :)

Comment: @vBx: It certainly sounds like the way you should go, yes. Tuple is not what you thought it was. :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. The size of the tuple is fixed and the element you want to access must be known at compile time.

Comment: So just how I thought i must know all the elements at compile time and use make_tuple()....